# Purchase Status API doesn't work with test purchases

Tags: android, in-app-billing, google-play-games

I'm adding receipt verification to my android app for in app purchases and I'm testing it with android.test.purchased sku. However, I'm always getting a 400 back from Google when I ask about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purchase status API doesn't seem to work with android.test.purchased. If I use it with an In App Purchase I've setup in the Developer Console it works fine.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you setup an In App Purchase using the developer console?